# Problem using greedy and non-greedy regular expressions

Tags: python, regex, non-greedy

I can't understand what I am doing wrong. I only need to extract router_name and port number. 
the router name is "`C1900_ROUTER1_SR7`" and port is "4/1/4" and it could exist "`B:C1900_ROUTER1_SR7`......" instead of "`A:C1900_ROUTER1_SR7`.........."

```
string = "A:C1900_ROUTER1_SR7# 

A:C1900_ROUTER1_SR7# echo "<team:script>"

<team:script>

A:C1900_ROUTER1_SR7# /environment no more 

A:C1900_ROUTER1_SR7# 

A:C1900_ROUTER1_SR7# show port 4/1/4 

"

regex_S2 = '(A|B):(?P<routername>.*?)#\s*show port\s*(?P<port>.*?)\s*\n'

match_L0_iter = re.findall(regex_S2, string, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

The routername captured group results = `"C1900_ROUTER1_SR7# A:C1900_ROUTER1_SR7# echo "<pnm:script>" <pnm:script> A:C1900_ROUTER1_SR7# /environment no more A:C1900_ROUTER1_SR7# A:C1900_ROUTER1_SR7"`

Comment: Remove `re.DOTALL`, see [this demo](https://regex101.com/r/8okC5u/1)

Comment: yes, but is forgot to say that is a .txt file and there is a lot of lines like this! If i remove re.DOTALL, i will no match the entire string. I need to continue matching other words after router name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could update your pattern to match non whitespace chars at the end instead of a non greedy `.*?` To match the router name, you might also use a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated) `[^#]+` matching any char except a `#`

To match either A or B you could use a character class.

```
[AB]:(?P<routername>[^#]+)#\s*show port\s*(?P<port>\S+)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2xqPmx/1)

If you must match the rest of the line as well including a newline, you can append `\s*\n` as in your pattern.